# Splitting a collection with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but I can't come up with it...

I have a collection with a Group string field. What I'd like to do is split that collection into (n) number of collections for each Group. I'll end up with a loop similar to this:

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
   foreach (var item in group)
   {
      //process item.
   }
}
```

Any guidance out there??? Thanks!

Edit for example:

Given this:

```
var people = new List();
people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" });
people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Barker" });
people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Billy", LastName = "Barker" });
people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Billy", LastName = "Bob" });
```

I'd like to get a collection with 3 elements.  Element 1 will be a collection of people (the Does), Element  2 will be a collection of people (The Barkers), Element  3 will be a collection with Billy Bob.

Comment: Describe the collection element type a bit more. Elaborate with an example - sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe, [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) will help?

```
var grouped = groups.GroupBy(g => g.Group);
```

Comment: GroupBy was the key.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: made it fit the example. We group people by their last name, iterate over the groups, then iterate over each person inside each group

```
var groupedCollection = from person in people
                        group person by person.LastName; // or use .GroupBy()
foreach (var group in groupedCollection)
{
    var lastName = group.Key;
    foreach (var person in group)
    {
        // do stuff with person
    }
}
```

Read up on more grouping samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754)

Comment: This seems to get me the distinct group names. I'd like to isolate the items in the collection that fall into the groups. See my edit for an example.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the input.  I was looking at the result of the GroupBy operation incorrectly.  It does do what I want it to do.  LINQ FTW!